# Azure Service Bus sender - opt out of automatic Diagnostic-Id setting

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

We are using the .NET SDK for Azure Service Bus (Azure.Messaging.Servicebus v7.17.3) to receive messages, process them again and putting a new (scheduled) message on the same Service Bus. However, since [the SDK automatically adds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-end-to-end-tracing?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2) the `Diagnostic-Id` header with the previous tracing value, we basically end up with one, never ending trace. For example, when looking at Application Insights.

So I'm looking for an easy way to opt out of this behavior. Basically, I would like to be each processing instance to be a closed trace, not spanning on to the next execution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to opt-out of tracing instrumentation for the Service Bus library.  However, the scenario that you're describing isn't the intended experience.

When `ServiceBusMessage` is created from a `ServiceBusReceivedMessage`, it should be resetting the diagnostic identifier so that a new one is minted when the message is sent/scheduled.  It is currently not doing that; this is a bug.  I'll see if we can get a fix together for the next release (17.7.4)

Comment: It would be good to link to the issue.

Comment: If there was an issue, I would have.   :)   Once I put out the PR, I'll link that here.

Comment: No worries. I thought it was an existing issue.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/pull/42261

Comment: I see. But this would only apply when using `ServiceBusMessage(ServiceBusReceivedMessage receivedMessage)`!? I'm not using that method at the moment (and it would not be trivial in our setup to move to that). Any other option? Like manually setting the Diagnostic-Id property to something?

Comment: @silent: Then I'm not following the scenario.  The behavior doesn't sound like it's intended.  Can you open an issue in the Azure SDK for .NET repository with the full details so that we can take a look?   https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues